# How to add control to grid cell in designer without editing XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, designer

I want to add control into WPF Grid cell 0,0 just by using mouse&menus.

I can easily do it

- by editing XAML code in designer, adding `<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>`
- programmatically in C# or VB.NET

To my surprise I found out *I'm unable to add it simply by using mouse & menus*. If I use drag&drop, control (yellow) is not inserted into specific cell of grid, but placed where I dropped it, ignoring cell boundaries (the grid is highlighted by orange):

[image]

How can I add control into cell 0,0 just by clicking in designer?

I've checked few online tutorials, authors always go the XAML way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your steps :

  1. Hover around the layout near edges of layout in designer till see see a yellow line.

  2. Click to create grid rows and columns when u see this yellow line
  to create rows and columns.

  3. Drag a control and place it in the grid at a corner (to avoid Margins) Your mouse pointer should stand near the pointer for this to occur.

  4. In case of a mistake use the locks near the margins to turn on or of the margin.

  5. Even after placing drag to the corner is possible.

*Please notice the XAML Generated.*

Refer attached:

[image: Attached in an image with a grid created using above steps]

Comment: Now I see the thing I was missing was that I cannot position the control by **initial** drag&drop operation. The control can be placed correctly by **second** drag&drop.